# Typescript Super Type

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a type which is a the super type of T?
Something like:

```
foo<T>(obj: Super<T>): T
```

Lets say T is an object with properties of **{ username, password }**.
Super < T > with properties of **{ username, password, confirmPassword }**.

Example of a function signature:

```
function excludeKeys<T>(obj: Super<T>, excludeKeys: string[]): T {

    // Exclude key/pairs form original object ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the parent with `T extends U` so TypeScript can infer the parent type:

```
function foo<T extends U, U>(obj: U): T { ... }
```

Or you could try something like this:

```
type Super<T> = T extends infer U ? U : object;

function foo<T>(obj: Super<T>): T { ... }
```

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer, is there any solution without involving U?

Comment: @Dachstein, you are welcome. I tried `type Super<T> = T extends infer U ? U : object` but TypeScript does not seem to infer the parent type and simply returns `T`. So I don't know any other solution that would work without involving `U`.

Comment: I just tried your type `Super<T> = T extends infer U ? U : object` and it works on my side. So that was the solution I was looking for. But you said that TypeScript does not seem to infer the parent type and simple returns T? I have tested it with my above example. Having two objects, where the parent has exactly one more key/value pair.

Comment: @Dachstein, Oh ok! Then I will add it in the answer, I must have made a mistake when testing it...